# How to downgrade the phpadmin in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to connect to remote database server with `phpadmin` on my home system. My Server uses `Mysql` version `5.1.61` and this `mysql` version is very old for the new `xampp phpadmin` version. I am thinking to downgrade the `phpadmin` version in xammpp 5.6.8

But I am getting an error due to compatibility error.

Error:

> SQL query: Edit Edit
> SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Comment: Did you do the downgrade? If so, which phpMyAdmin version did you install in your XAMPP?

Comment: I could not downgrade the phpadmin. I tried downgrade the xampp but still connecting to remote mysql didn't work. Then I used mysql workbench to connect to remote database.

Comment: You could downgrade just phpMyAdmin. Use version 4.0.10.10 from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ and replace your phpMyAdmin wit h this one.

Answer (score -1):

"utf8mb4" is an extended character set used in Mysql 5.5.3 and higher. Try converting the DB to use utf8 only instead of utf8mb4.

Below URL might help.

http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/201740/script-to-convert-mysql-collation-from-utf8mb4-to-utf8

Comment: `utf8mb4` is not an “extended” character set. Rather, what MySQL calls `utf8` is a subset of UTF-8 limited to a maximum of 3 bytes per character, which means only the Basic Multilingual Plane can be encoded. The server the OP has doesn’t support the “fixed” `utf8mb4` character set introduced in 5.5.3 so they can hardly convert anything. It’s the PHPAdmin version that’s too new here.